# JavaScript creating new objects

Tags: javascript, object

Currently I'm trying to have two instances of an auction run simultaneously, but it seems when I'm creating a new object it's the exact same object as the one before it.

## The Code:

Here is the code that creates the new object:

```
AuctionSell._state = new auctionGen();
AuctionSell._state.init(i);
auctions.push(AuctionSell._state);
```

To note, `auctionGen()` is a function that returns an object containing all the variables and logic surrounding the auction itself.

```
function auctionGen()
{
    return {
        //code
    }
}
```

^ this is just a blank template to show how the object is actually being created.

Updates the auctions array:

```
update : function(dt)
{
    if(auctions.length > 0)
    {
        for(var i = 0; i < auctions.length; ++i)
        {
            if(!auctions[i]._expired)
            {
                auctions[i].update(dt);
            }
            else
            {
                auctions.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I create the new object then push it into an array that will contain my auctions. This happens in the auction's `init` function which only gets called when a new auction is to be created. I've checked the data of both auction states and they contain the different vehicles that are up for auction, however it appears as if creating the new one halts the old one.

## Example:

If I run one auction alone - depending on the car - the final bid will always be higher than it's actual value. However, if I run these auctions simultaneously it is guaranteed to be under value.

I just ran two auctions simultaneously, the price of the first vehicle was `$18000` but the Auction ended with a bid of `$6370`. The second car was valued at `$57,000` and the Auction ended at `$46428`.

All of the bids are done by AI, and they are programmed to always stop bidding at a certain point above the value of the vehicle. This issue only appears when running two or more auctions at one time.

## The Question

Is there another method in which I should be creating these objects to make them truly new objects? As of right now they seem to interfere with each other.

### Edit:

After changing the update call to be the following:

```
update : function(dt)
{
    var i;
    if(auctions.length > 0)
    {
        i = 0;
        while(i < auctions.length)
        {
            if(!auctions[i]._expired)
            {
                auctions[i].update(dt);
                ++i;
            }
            else
            {
                auctions.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and fixing my `ai` array to no longer be global, it seems as though the issue now only occurs on the second vehicle auction. The bidding for the `$57,000` vehicle stopped at `$17,198` where my `$12,000` vehicle stopped at `$23,947` (intended behaviour)

Comment: have you used something like firebug to see what exactly is inside of these objects?

Comment: Your `new` will almost certainly be unnecessary here, unless you use `this` inside your `auctionGen()` constructor, since you're returning from `auctionGen()`.

Comment: Does the object returned from auctionGen() happen to reference any variables?

Comment: `function auctionGen(){}` should return `this` after initialization

Comment: @RubenKazumov: No, not the function as shown, which returns a newly-object.

Comment: @ElGuapo - Yes I have, that's how I know the vehicles are being loaded into the auction properly, and everything appears to be in order. @BDawg - You just reminded me that my `ai` array is actually global (cheap hack for the prototype - it wasn't me I swear!), I'm going to go back and fix that and see if that solves the issue.

Comment: Consider `Array.prototype.filter()` in `update()` method

Comment: p.s... I hope these auctions that are ending early aren't real auctions ;).

Comment: As it turns out, the ai was only the problem for the first vehicle. The second one seems to get shorted where the first auction goes to it's intended final bid.

Answer (score 5):

You have a bug in your `update` code: If you remove an entry (your `splice` call), you don't want to increment `i`, it's making you skip entries — suppose you have entries `0`, `1`, and `2`; when processing `1`, you remove it; now the entry that used to be at `2` is at `1`, so if you increment `i`, you'll skip it.

Instead, only increment `i` if you're not removing the entry:

```
update : function(dt)
{
    var i;
    if(auctions.length > 0)             // *** There's no reason to do this
    {
        i = 0;                          // *** Change on this line
        while (i < auctions.length)     // *** Change on this line
        {
            if(!auctions[i]._expired)
            {
                auctions[i].update(dt);
                ++i;                    // *** Note we increment `i`
            }
            else
            {
                auctions.splice(i, 1);  // *** Removing, so don't increment `i`
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for catching this, I've changed it now and that actually solved the issue that the second vehicle would be under bid, however it still happens for the first auctioned vehicle. Changing my `ai` array as it is global, which a comment on my post made me notice, once I fix that I will check back in.

Comment: Yeah, if you have a global array, it's not going to be instance-specific. :-)

Comment: Updated OP with results

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to carelessly manipulate the container (the array in this case) as you walk over it. In C++ this would be called iterator invalidation, but the idea is the same here: `i` is getting messed up and pointing to the wrong data. Your `splice` call is causing your loop to skip some entries.

Comment: It's totally fine to remove entries as you move through the array, you just have to handle it properly, as I explained 10 minutes ago.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I added the word "carelessly." I thoroughly enjoyed your explanation but felt it was worth it to draw the analogy to other languages and introduce extant terminology for this issue.